# How to enable loopTime for animation clips (FBX and others) in Unity 2017.1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a FBX model with animation clips as subassets (embeded in it), I want to enable looping for all clips in it. I found that `AnimationUtility`'s `GetClipSettings` method is obsolete now and also tried using it but it didn't work. This is probably because Unity has changed their API for looping and it seems that the only way to access loopTime property is by manually  accessing the subassets of fbx model and checking the loopTime property. However, I have to automate this process since I'm generating dynamic animation controllers for my models before building assetbundles. The pipeline includes post/pre-processing and then building assetbundles through editor scripts. So far, I have come across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743329/rename-animation-clips-when-importing-in-the-editor/42747047#42747047) using which I was able to enable loopTime just by setting `ModelImporterClipAnimation.loopTime = true` for every clip and it works. However, now the model seems to look completely pink as it loses reference to its materials for whatever reason, this happens only when I include the AssetPostprocessing script.

How should this be dealt with?

Why is the model losing materials if the `OnPreprocessAnimation` of `AssetPostprocessor` is included? Am I missing something?

Should I also handle Material references by some other method, if I mess with the `AssetPostprocessor`?

Can we access loopTime by some other way? It is not specified in the docs, though.

My code is exactly the same as the referenced post above other than the slight change to enable loopTime. Or is there a better way to do all this?

P.S. I'm posting this question after a day full of searching and experimenting, apologies in advance if the question is not clear enough. I can add more info if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have to handle the material yourself. You can set [`ModelImporter.importMaterials`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ModelImporter-importMaterials.html) to `false` to create a default diffuse material when importing the model.

If material already exist, you can also search for existing material and load it when importing the model:

```
ModelImporter modelImporter = (ModelImporter)assetImporter;
modelImporter.materialName = ModelImporterMaterialName.BasedOnMaterialName;
modelImporter.materialSearch = ModelImporterMaterialSearch.Local;
```

See [`ModelImporterMaterialName`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ModelImporterMaterialName.html) and [`ModelImporterMaterialSearch`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ModelImporterMaterialSearch.html) docs for other options you have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful. I deleted the project and ran the build again then for some reason it seemed to work properly. The only thing I have added is the below snippet on top of the existing AssetPostprocessor script. Not sure if this is the reason for it to work now, I'm just going to go with it for now.

`Material OnAssignMaterialModel(Material mat, Renderer rend){
        return null;
    }`

Comment: I didn't have this problem too and was wondering why it was happening. Anyways, it's a good thing you can also specify the material from code like I did. Glad you solved it.